i am trying to import excel sheet data with some columns containing richtext(bold/italic) in laravel. But it gives plain text rather than richtext
it always print '0' for richtext in sheet in cell 'D2'. is there anything need to do while creating sheet in excel for richtext format before upload file?
public function import()
    {
        $file = request()->file('file')->store('import_files');
        $path = storage_path('app/' . $file);
        $spreadsheet = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::load($path);
        $cellValue = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getCell('D2')->getValue();

        if ($cellValue instanceof \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\RichText\RichText) {
            dd('1');
        }
        dd('0');
    }

i have used many thing but no luck.
